boost::property_tree not deallocating memory
I am using boost::property_tree to parse a json file(~350kB), with boost 1.74 on Ubuntu 22.04.
After trying to parse a json file into a ptree, when ptree gets out of scope it seems not to be deallocated.
Code is as follows:
int main() {
    
    std::string path("../files/testFile.json");
    sleep(2);
    try {
        boost::property_tree::ptree its_tree;
        boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(path, its_tree);
        its_tree.clear();
        std::cout << "File was read" << std::endl;
        sleep(2);
    } catch (boost::property_tree::json_parser_error&) {
        std::cout << "Failed reading json" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Destroyed ptrees" << std::endl;
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}

When monitoring resident memory by calling cat /proc/{PID}/status | grep RSS it is visible that allocated memory does not decrease after ptree gets out of context:
17:19:55: VmRSS: 3584 kB
File was read
17:19:56: VmRSS: 5504 kB
17:19:57: VmRSS: 5504 kB
Destroyed ptrees
17:19:58: VmRSS: 5504 kB
17:19:59: VmRSS: 5504 kB
17:20:00: VmRSS: 5504 kB


Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

You are looking the memory occupied by a process; memory allocators inside applications (like the one used by C++) don't return memory to the operating system -- at least not right away.; it would be far too inefficient. Also, since memory allocations aren't usually done in page sizes by the application, deallocating some memory might not even free a page that could be returned to the operating system.
